# "Jon Skeet" reputation bug

Tags: support, reputation

I was searching up our old buddy Jon Skeet on the user's page on Stackoverflow to see his current rep when I encountered is some bug that causes it to show that Jon Skeet has become broke and has just 3,000 rep. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users)is the link. To confirm that it was a bug, I reloaded my page but I still get the same thing. I have attached a screenshot as proof:-

[image: Poor Jon skeet]

And if you open him up (I mean his profile) you get that lovely "nearly 1.2m rep"

[image: Proof!]

Obviously, this is a bug which on the SO site which may not be much of concern to us, but maybe to Mr.Skeet... So when is this gonna be fixed up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number you're seeing there is the amount of reputation the user has received *this month*:

[image]

If you want to see *total* reputation, go to the "all" tab instead, and it'll be displayed as you're expecting.

[image]

Comment: 1177k lol. when are they gonna add 1.2m in the rep field??

Comment: @neelg Please see [How to format reputation when Jon Skeet hits 1 million+ rep next year?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339819/4642212).